# Extjs Changing color of bars in stacked bar chart

Tags: extjs, colors, charts, bar-chart, stacked

let's take [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/charts/StackedBar.js)... how to change colors of those bars?

I know I can change it via renderer but it won't change legend.

I have tried to use:

```
style: {fill: 'red'}
```

but it changes color of ever bar

I have tried to put colors in array, its not working.

I have tried to put each style in array, like this:

```
style: [{fill: 'red'}, {fill: 'green'}, {fill: 'blue'}]
```

But it won't work either, since I can put titles in array like:

```
title: ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
```

I thought it (styles) should work too but not.

So how can I change color of each "data" bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bar colors are actually determined by the [chart's theme](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.chart.theme.Theme):

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    theme: 'myTheme'
    //the remainder of your code...
});
```

In order to use custom colors, you will need to extend the existing 'Base' theme, as in the [custom area chart example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/charts/Area%20-%20BrowserStats.html).

Answer (score 4):

Chart uses Theme as mixins

So you can directly use theme property called themeAttrs.

For example if you are in constructor of column/stacked column chart, want to change the color of columns You can specify

```
this.themeAttrs.colors = ['#F2C72B','#a5c249','#E88712','#9D5FFA'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.onReady(function() 
{

  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', 
  {
    title: 'Pie1 Chart',
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 400,
    items: 
    [{
      xtype: 'chart',
      animate:false ,
      insetPadding:0,

      legend: 
    {
        position: 'right'
        },
      shadow: true,
      store: 
    {
        fields: 
    [{
          name: 'category', type: 'string'
        },

    {
          name: 'data', type: 'float'
        }],
        data: 
    [{
          category: 'Alive', data: 1.5
        },{
          category: 'Dead', data: 2 
        },{
          category: 'Standby', data: 1
        }]
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        field: 'data',
     colorSet: ['#0000FF','#FFffff','#00FF00'],

        showInLegend: true, <!--It is use to display data in which color.-->
        highlight: {
          segment: {
            margin: 20
          }
        },
        label: {
          field: 'category',
          display: 'rotate',
          contrast: true,
          font: '18px Arial'
        }
      }]
    }]
  }).show();  
});
```

using  colorSet you can change color.

Answer (score 1):

I decided add full code:

```
Ext.require('EAM.view.chart.*');
Ext.define('EAM.view.chart.integral.IntegralChart',
{
    extend : 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    alias : 'widget.GroupsIntegralChart',
    animate : true,
    shadow : true,
    // theme : 'Browser:gradients',

    initComponent : function()
    {
        var me = this;
        me.themeAttrs.colors =
        [
            'orange',
            'red',
            'blue',
            'green',
        ];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a **theme**, you can use this (at least it worked for me):

```
this.series = [{
type: 'column',
axis: 'left',
showInLegend : true,
xField: 'f1',
style :{
    fill :  '#ff00ff',
    'stroke-width': 3,
    width: 20
},
renderer: function(sprite, storeItem, barAttr, i, store) {
    barAttr.fill = '#ff00ff';
    barAttr.width = 20;
    return barAttr;
},
title : 'title',
yField: 'f2'
}]
```

Note that you have to put your color in two different lines (I think ExtJS is sometimes kinda stupid framework).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ext JS 5.0
 There is no need to worry,just include colors config in series.

```
series : [{
        type : 'bar',
        colors:['#f23f3f','#ff8809','#ff0','#0039a6','#00ee88','#ff8aed'],
        xField : ['Q1']
        yField : ['Critical', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Warning', 'Informational',   'Indeterminent']
}]
```